# How would I get the last "date" from a JSON file?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file. The entries in the file may not be in order.

How would I get the last calendar date entry.

The JSON file looks like

```
[
    {
        "name": "Vacant",
        "date": "02/6/2017",
        "title": "Division Manager",
        "mondayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Main Campus PM"
    },
    {
        "name": "Vacant",
        "date": "02/13/2017",
        "title": "Division Manager",
        "mondayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Main Campus PM"
    },
    {
        "name": "Vacant",
        "date": "02/20/2017",
        "title": "Division Manager",
        "mondayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Main Campus PM"
    },
    {
        "name": "Vacant",
        "date": "02/20/2018",
        "title": "IT Division Manager",
        "mondayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Main Campus PM"
    }
]
```

Please let me know if there is a quick way of finding out using LINQ
The only pattern for the date is that it will always be a Monday.

My CalendarModel.cs File

```
class CalendarModel
{
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public string date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mondayAM")]
        public string mondayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mondayPM")]
        public string mondayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tuesdayAM")]
        public string tuesdayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tuesdayPM")]
        public string tuesdayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("wednesdayAM")]
        public string wednesdayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("wednesdayPM")]
        public string wednesdayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thursdayAM")]
        public string thursdayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thursdayPM")]
        public string thursdayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fridayAM")]
        public string fridayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fridayPM")]
        public string fridayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("saturdayAM")]
        public string saturdayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("saturdayPM")]
        public string saturdayPM { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is this all of the JSON? I only see one date.

Comment: Please specify your question, we know nothing about your code you are using, what library or json parser you have. Do you have model in c# and so on...

Comment: I didnt add the other 2Objects but it repeats with the date changed and the AM/PM items.

Answer (score 0):

Your question (currently) does not contain a lot of information, so this is something of a guess.  If your question is updated and is actually about the JSON processing itself, I will most likely delete this answer.

I am going to assume that you are somehow processing your JSON into a list of objects similar to this:

```
public class ScheduleEntry
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime DateStamp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // Plus the rest of the properties
}
```

Assuming that you have some kind of processing method, you would simply have something like this:

```
private void ProcessSchedule()
{
    List<ScheduleEntry> scheduleList = new List<ScheduleEntry>();

    // [Processing from JSON Done Here]

    // [Done Processing]

    DateTime maxDate = scheduleList.Max(o => o.DateStamp);
}
```